# file not exist error in cygwin

Tags: unix, maven, cygwin, maven-3

I am executing the maven command from **E drive with different settings.xml file located at H drive.**

I am getting the following error.

Its taking E as base directory.

```
user1234@abcavbavb17 /cygdrive/E/repo
# mvn clean install -gs /cygdrive/H/settings.xml
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] The specified global settings file does not exist: E:\cygdrive\H\setting
s.xml
```

Please tell me the fix for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please correct me, if I'm wrong. It should be `/cygdrive/H/settings.xml`.

Comment: @CharleeChitsuk. Sorry It is typo error in the question. Edited it.

Comment: Have you tried to use `/H/settings.xml` instead ?

Comment: Yeah I have tried, but no luck

Comment: Try 'H:\settings.xml' or using relative paths